# Does Avro handle UUIDs or java.util.Date?

Tags: java, serialization, avro

I see that [Apache Avro](https://avro.apache.org) does not write [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID)s or [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects. Is there some way I can make it write the same?

I have UUIDs and Dates spread all over my java classes that need to be serialized. So I do not want to go and put some annotation on each one of them.

I am looking for some options such that:

1. Avro directly writes the UUID/Date fields and then reads back the same as well.
2. I can plugin my custom encoder/decoder like avro.addCustomEncoder (UUID.class, MyEncoder)

Answer (score 2):

There is an Avro ticket to fix this:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1554

Answer (score 0):

For the date fields if you use IDL style you can do like

union {null, string} date = null;